# Cannot get redis 5 to run with systemctl

Tags: linux, redis, systemd, systemctl

Installed Redis 5 (have Redis 3 working on server)

Modified various configurations in /etc/opt/rh/rh-redis5/redis.conf as necessary including setting supervised to "systemd" and setting daemonize to no. (I also tried "auto" for supervised with no luck).

But when I start it up with the following command

```
systemctl start rh-redis5-redis.service
```

I get the error below:

```
Dec 02 16:18:23 myserver systemd[1]: Starting   Redis persistent key-value database...
Dec 02 16:18:23 myserver systemd[1]: rh-redis5-redis.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 02 16:18:23 myserver systemd[1]: Failed to start Redis persistent key-value database.
Dec 02 16:18:23 myserver systemd[1]: Unit rh-redis5-redis.service entered failed state.
Dec 02 16:18:23 myserver ystemd[1]: rh-redis5-redis.service failed.
```

rh-redis5-redis.service file has

```
[Unit]
Description=Redis persistent key-value database
After=network.target
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/rh/rh-redis5/root/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/opt/rh/rh-redis5/redis.conf --supervised systemd
ExecStop=/opt/rh/rh-redis5/root/usr/libexec/redis-  shutdown
Type=notify
User=redis
Group=redis
RuntimeDirectory=redis
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0755

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have seen others had this problem but other than changing supervised and daemonize I don't see any other remedies that would help me. Any suggestions?

Comment: Check the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permission in `/var, /var/log and /var/log/puppet` directory. when I install foreman I need to change `/var/log/puppet` permission to user `puppet` and set folder permission to `chmod 755 /var /var/log /var/log/puppet`